# Write a function that takes a dict as its input and returns the number of vowels

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to solve this question a bit now and I am currently stumped. 
Can someone show me a step by step solution or a way to go about this question?

Write a function that takes a dict as its input and returns the number of vowels contained within the dict's string keys.  For this exercise, you can consider a vowel to be the letters "a", "e", "i", "o", or "u".
I suppose an example would be count_dict_vowels({"Here": "Now", "When": "Python"}) == 3

Comment: Enjoying home work?

Comment: Not doing homework, just saw a problem that I have no idea how to approach. @mad_

Comment: `a={"Here": "Now", "When": "Python"}
vowel=['a','i','o','u','e']
temp_list=''.join(a.keys())
sum([1 for x in temp_list if x in vowel])`

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify how you wanted the output to look like so I created a new dictionary with the same keys but the number of vowels as the value.

The "trick" here is using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to take advantage of the `str` method `count()` and summing all the values.

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

sample_dict = {
    'abc': 'xyz',
    'ee': 'xyz',
    'aei': 'xyz',
    'uuu': 'xyz'
}

output_dict = {
    key: sum(map(key.count, vowels)) for key in sample_dict
}
```

Gives the output:

```
{'abc': 1, 'ee': 2, 'aei': 3, 'uuu': 3}
```

Comment: nice approach  :)

Comment: Iam ever wondering if this kind of solution on a lvl not near the OP level is snark in disguise ... nice solution.

Comment: I believe you want to count the vowels in the Values, not the keys. Just change to:  output_dict = {
 key: sum(map(val.count, vowels)) for key,val in sample_dict.iteritems()
}

Comment: @Alg_D "Write a function that takes a dict as its input and returns the number of vowels contained within the dict's string keys." I think this is already correct.

Comment: Arda Arslan, right :), I just look to the code since it looks interisting and pythonic. Then just tought... :)

Comment: It said to count the keys itself that are strings  but I could be wrong since the wording of the question is weird in my opinion @Alg_D